# Django sets model time field three hour less from my current local time

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'm following the [Django tutorial part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/) and have some troubles applying my local time to the models I've created.
This is my time config from settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                             
USE_I18N = True                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                               
USE_L10N = True                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                              
USE_TZ = True
```

These are models of my app. I suppose that an issue is somehow related with an error message that COC-Pyright gives. But this code have been just copied and pasted from official Django tutorial.

[image]

This picture shows actually my problem: time of record creating three hour less than my actual time

[image: This picture shows actually my problem: time of record creating three hour less than my actual time]

Comment: Django stores all datetimes in UTC, if you want to convert it to your timezone use `django.utils.timezone.localtime`

Comment: Set timezone `UTC` like `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`

Answer (score 0):

You should use "gte" insted of ">=" in your code.

self.pub_dat__gte = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

Comment: Django tutorial says I should do this: 
self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
But you know what? This is such untrusted source. I'll probably listen to your opinion.